# CSS ::selection, still blue in background

Tags: css, selection

When you use

```
::selection{
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

some parts of the site still have the blue when you select everything, is there anyway to fix this and make it so there is only a green background and no blue what so ever?

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle example.

Comment: You're not giving enough info for us to identify any problems.

Comment: How there this not enough info? When you select the whole page there are still blue parts and they need to be green, http://www.imgbomb.com/i/d15/xUZzz.png

Answer (score 2):

Those part happen in every site. It's normal. Take a look at mine: santz.net

I haave the same problem but it's a browser bug. Not a coding problem.

The code is okay. However, you might also need this for Mozilla

```
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}

::selection {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that it was a browser problem.
Kinda figured i was missing something.

Comment: Strange, but it's like that... Take a look at this screenshot: http://k43.kn3.net/65B81C329.jpg - on Santz I use light blue for background and a dark gray for color, but still some part of the menu for instance show off a blue that's not the one I defined. Good luck!

Comment: It says "403 - Forbidden".

Answer (score 0):

No problems here with the code you gave. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fWYZ/1/

HTML:

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
```

CSS:

```
::selection{
    background:green;
    color :white;
}
```